# How to go and get work in Silicon Valley without applying for visa by myself?

Tags: usa, working-visas

My dream is to go and get work in **Silicon Valley** (**USA**). But I heard that I would not get work visa directly (and if I say true, I don't want to apply for that for my self and waste my money in all visa processes and consultancy charges).

If I apply for one of the well reputed company there and if they would select me to work with them, then is it possible to go and work there? If yes, then how? What can be the steps for this? How I would get visa stamp on my passport?

By thew way, I'm from India and having expertise (experience) in software industry for more than 3 years. I've completed masters even I've good control over English language.

Comment: *I've good control over english language* - ....  First off this may be more appropriate for expatriates.SE rather then here.  Second I am not exactly clear on whether you want to work without a visa or just want to know how to get a work visa for the US?

Comment: I don't want to apply for Visa for my self. I only want to apply for a company there, and if they would select me then all other visa process (and charges) would be filled by them only. Is it possible? If yes, then what will be the process of it?

Comment: Btw, I asked this question here, only because this site gives the answer which are related to travelling. I told that `..I've good control over english language.` to let people know what I'm actually and based on that they would tell me the exact scenario of this.

Comment: What you're asking about isn't traveling but expatriation.  And if they will make an offer they will sponsor a work visa for you but that doesn't mean that you won't have to do anything.  While the majority of paperwork will be on their end you will still need to apply and go through an interview process.

Comment: While a quick search didn't turn up an exact duplicate, you may want to look and/or post on [The Workplace](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The visa process, unfortunately, is something that you have to do yourself. The company makes you the offer, sends a letter, and then you have to apply for a visa yourself along with the letter from the company. The US visa process, if you come up with good paperwork and eligible, is a painless process. But still, you have to do it yourself. As other suggested, I think expats SE would be good fit for this question.

Comment: @AyeshK, Thanks for the comments, that's the only thing I wanted to know ! :)

Comment: @AyeshK you couldn't be farther from the truth here. At least in the US, you cannot apply for a work visa on your own. Your employer applies for an approval for you, and only when the employer gets this approval - you can apply for the visa. Once the employer gets the approval, the visa process is more or less straight forward, and they only verify that the approval was given based on the true facts. The main hurdle is for the employer to get that approval.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to find an employer either in India or in the US, who would be willing to work on transferring you to work there.

There are two main options:

1. Get hired directly by a US employer as a foreign worker. You'll need to get a H1b visa, for which the employer will have to file a petition. These visas are limited in quantity, and the process should start more or less a year before the expected start date. [Read more on h1b visas here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H-1B_visa).
2. Get hired by an Indian employer, who will transfer you to a related (subsidiary/sister/parent) company in the US some time in the future. In this case you'll need an L1 visa, which is relatively easier to get. You'll probably have to work 2-3 years in India before your employer will approve such a transfer. [Read more about L1 visas here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-1_visa).

You can read about the specific visa application process and charges on [the US Embassy website](http://newdelhi.usembassy.gov/applyingmain.html).